# Error: 'color' attribute should be defined

Tags: android-selector

A color selector is defined as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#66666666" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/translucent_icon_background" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In Android Studio, 'item" is marked red indicating an error as shown by the following screenshot:
[image]

The app works fine per tests.  I am asking because I am afraid it may not be fine on some devices due to that error.  Could anyone shed some light on this error?  More specifically, can it be ignored?

Comment: For me it compile the app but the OS define a different color that the one i was expecting for.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error and I removed it by adding a color attribute with the item tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff">  <--**add this** 
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/gray" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ffffff"> **<--add this** 
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#66666666" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:color="#ffffff">   **<--add this** 
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/translucent_icon_background" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the 'selector.xml' in the 'drawable/' folder rather than 'color/' folder.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZa2K.png)